# Meaning of different options used while running a shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I was reading a shell script and I  found the below command there.
I tried searching on Google thinking `attach`, `force` and `delete` are the options used while running a script. But failed to find anything. Can anyone please explain what exactly the command below does? Please explain the usage of every single entity.

```
./filename.sh -attach -force -delete -ctxtype 1
```

Comment: hello, `./filename.sh` is command, others are options to `./filename.sh`. If you post contents of filename.sh, we can tell you what `-attach`, `-force` is doing in filename.sh

Comment: ok, this simply means I have to somehow get that script file also to understand what options are doing. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the script is invoked as `./filename.sh` rather than `filename.sh` because the current directory (`.`) is not in the `PATH` by default in most distributions. In other words, if you give your shell a command name without a full path, it will not look for that command in the current directory. This is why the `./` part is needed.

As for `-attach` and co., they are, as you understand, options to the script. The operative word here is *the*. They are options used when running *this* script rather than when running *a* script. To understand what these options do, you need to look at the script itself and/or any documentation that came with it. You can try

```
./filename.sh -h
```

to see the help message if the script's author has provided any.

Finally, the lone `1` at the end is an argument. It may be an argument to the `-ctxtype` switch or, if that switch does not need an argument, then it's an argument to the script itself. Again, you have to look at the script itself to understand what each switch is supposed to do.